# How to use provider data from place where no BuildContext available

Tags: flutter, provider

I need to call a provider data from a class Which doesn't extend any state classes

```
class Services {

  static listenForMessage(){
    var handler = webSocketHandler((webSocket) {
    webSocket.stream.listen((message) {
      Provider.of<ProviderClass>(context).chatsList.clear();// context unavailable
      webSocket.sink.add("echo $message");
    });
  });

  serve(handler, 'localhost', 8080).then((server) {
    print('Serving at ws://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
  });
  }
}
```

But there is no context available in this class, how can I call this data without `BuildContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to receive the context in the function arguments and send it where your function is required?

```
static listenForMessage(context){...}
```

Comment: aah.. I forgot that this function is to be called from a state class. My mistake. (how can I forget it..)

Answer (score -1):

i have found a link that might help you, not 100% sure
https://maneesha-erandi.medium.com/handling-api-requests-with-flutter-provider-944e3258c5ca